# How to fix push notification ios issue while app in background in ionic1/cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification

i am using https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/ and everything working fine in Android platform and Ios platform just facing issue in 1 condition- 
IOS - when app in background notification appear in device , when click in notification so onNotificationOpen method doesn't work.

### List of plugins i had

```
cordova-android-support-gradle-release 1.4.4 "cordova-android-support-gradle-release",
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion",
cordova-plugin-broadcaster 3.0.1 "broadcaster",
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera",
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat",
cordova-plugin-console 1.1.0 "Console",
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.7 "Device",
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File",
cordova-plugin-file-opener2 2.0.19 "File Opener2",
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer",
cordova-plugin-firebase 2.0.5 "Google Firebase Plugin",,
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.4 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.1 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.2.1 "SocialSharing"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.6.0 "Toast"
cordova-sqlite-storage 2.2.0 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
es6-promise-plugin 4.1.0 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
pushwoosh-cordova-plugin 7.8.0 "Pushwoosh"
```

I provided - grantPermission and build using legacy build system , and i am not using any local notification plugin.

```
window.FirebasePlugin.onNotificationOpen(function (notification) { 
//while tap on notification doesn't come to this function when app is in background
})
```

Comment: You mean you app is suspended or just in background?

Comment: just in background

Comment: if i close app then reopen so working fine but issue in background

Comment: strange.. there is a method 'sendNotification' on iOS that is called from every push receive callback https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/search?q=sendNotification&unscoped_q=sendNotification .

Comment: Do you use any other plugins that provide some push or local notifications things? e.g. Cordova local notifications plugin or so. I remember it could be some conflict between these 2

Comment: no i am not using any other plugin for notification related , i am jut usingpushwoosh-cordova-plugin for handling some user logged events

Comment: So you use both FCM and pushwoosh plugins, right?

Comment: Yes i am using both plugin FCM and pushwoosh

Comment: Hi thanks for answering,  my issue is solved and was because of conflict between pushwoosh plugin and FCM. 
again thank you :)